# JMETER user based or throughput based testing

Tags: jmeter, throughput

I want to know how much users the system I am testing can handle and I am confused which test to use in JMeter, user-based where I user specific number of threads or throughput based where I use the throughput timer and from there I calculate the number of concurrent users.

Answer (score 0):

You have answered your question yourself, if you need to know how many **users** your system is able to handle you need to simulate real users as close as possible, it includes:

- Cookies ([HTTP Cookie Manager](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Cookie_Manager))
- Cache ([HTTP Cache Manager](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Cache_Manager))
- Headers ([HTTP Header Manager](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Header_Manager))
- Think Time ([Timers](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#timers))
- Your application usage scenarios (user groups distributions)

Start with one and gradually increase the load until response time will start exceeding acceptable or errors start occurring, whatever comes the first.

See [How To Make JMeter Behave More Like A Real Browser](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/206733719-How-to-make-JMeter-behave-more-like-a-real-browser) article for more information on above hints.

Comment: The thing is that I knew how much throughput the system can handle (40 RPS) more than that errors start to occur.. but I don't know what is the think time to calculate the number of concurrent users the system can handle. I am using this formula (CCU=RPS*(think time+Avg. response time) ).